# Spotify automatic "offline mode" when no Wifi connection

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to automatically switch my Android Spotify app to "offline mode" when not connected to Wifi?

I've just had 1.5GB of data downloaded via Mobile data connection which has over maxed out my limit!

I'm not sure why this has happened (I can only assume it's re-downloaded some playlists?), but I would like to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: Check on settings that download is available only over wi-fi.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do that, if your device runs at least Android [4.0](/questions/tagged/4.0):

1. From your homescreen, go to *Settings → Data Usage*
2. tick the checkbox to enable data limit
3. in the graph, move the bars to some level suiting you (can be imaginary high, to not toggle your mobile data off altogether when reached)
4. scroll down until you find the Spotify app, tap its entry to open details
5. scroll to the end of that screen, tick the checkbox to "limit background data"

Done. Now, unless Spotify is running in foreground, it should no longer automatically use mobile data.

This setting has no effect to WiFi, so it would perfectly fit your needs: while on WiFi, Spotify feels no restriction. As soon as you switch to mobile data, the app is no longer allowed to automatically transfer anything in background – but should still permit actions you trigger when the app is in foreground.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings and untick "Download over 2G/3G".

This way Spotify won't download/update playlists when WiFi connection is not available.

It can however still stream music, so to disable that just tick the "Offline mode" option.

If you leave it ticked it won't stream music anymore and you will be only able to listen to previously downloaded playlists. Also, you settings will be preserved and the next time you start Spotify it will still be in Offline mode, preventing unwanted Mobile data traffic.

Comment: On my app, this today reads 'Download using cellular' and defaults to Off - glad to see before heading out of my apartment!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to programmatically toggle offline mode (ie, by creating an Intent or with Tasker or something). However you can limit streaming quality over mobile networks, same with downloading of offline playlists.

Spotify is aware of some users having problems with high data usage, and some of the recent 1.x releases have contained fixes for these types of problems. So always make sure that you have the latest version of the Spotify app installed!